# SSRS2005 Report works in builder and manager, but not in viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a report that I built in VB2005. It works perfectly in the report builder, and it works in the report manager on the server.

I have an aspx page, however, with a report viewer and it returns 0 results.

The report renders, but returns no data.

Here is my SQL Code:

```
SELECT        v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Subject, SO_Activity.Notes, SO_Activity.Date_Closed, SO_Activity.Last_Update, v_rpt_Member.Member_ID, 
                         v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_Desc, v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc
FROM            v_rpt_Company LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         v_rpt_Member ON SO_Activity.Assign_To = v_rpt_Member.Member_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Company_Team ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID AND 
                         v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = Company_Team.Company_RecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         v_rpt_ActivityType ON SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Type_RecID = v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_RecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         v_rpt_ActivityStatus ON SO_Activity.so_act_status_recid = v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_RecID
WHERE        (@acctmgr <> 'true' OR Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1) AND 
                         (SO_Activity.Assign_To = @member) AND (v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc = CASE WHEN @act_status IS NULL 
                         THEN v_rpt_ActivityStatus.so_act_status_desc ELSE @act_status END) AND ((@company = '') OR (v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = @company)) AND (SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101)) AND (SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101))
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Subject, SO_Activity.Notes, SO_Activity.Date_Closed, SO_Activity.Last_Update, v_rpt_Member.Member_ID, 
                         v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_Desc, v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Last_Update DESC
```

Here is my asp.net code:

```
<div style="text-align:center;border-style:solid;border-width:3px; width:auto;height:auto;">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        Height="700px" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" ShowParameterPrompts="False">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/path/report" ReportServerUrl="http:myserver/reportserver" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

And here is my C#:

```
   /*
     * Retrieve parameters from URL and send them to the report
     */
    private void getParametersFromURL()
    {
        //Load Parameters from URL
        //Requests that are commented, are commented because of lack of ConnectWise Support
        String[] parameters = new String[7];
        parameters[0] = Request.QueryString["acctmgr"];
        parameters[1] = Request.QueryString["member"];
        parameters[2] = Request.QueryString["details"];
        parameters[3] = Request.QueryString["act_status"];
        parameters[4] = Request.QueryString["company"];
        parameters[5] = Request.QueryString["date_start"];
        parameters[6] = Request.QueryString["date_end"];

        //Create Parameter Collection Array
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[parameters.Length];
        //Loop through each parameter and load the name and value into the parameter collection
        int i = 0;
        foreach (String parameter in parameters)
        {
            reportParameterCollection[i] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter();
            reportParameterCollection[i].Name = getParameterName(i);
            reportParameterCollection[i].Values.Add(Convert.ToString(parameters[i]));
            i++;
        }

        //Load Parameters into the ReportViewer
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }

    /*
     * Takes the index of the element in the parameter array 
     * then returns the correct parameter name to return to the report viewer
     */
    public String getParameterName(int number)
    {
        switch (number)
        {
            case 0:
                return "AcctMgr";
            case 1:
                return "member"; 
            case 2:
                return "details";
            case 3:
                return "act_status";
            case 4:
                return "company";
            case 5:
                return "date_start";
            case 6:
                return "date_end";
            default:
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Error: getParameterName(number) failed. Parameter #: " + number + ");</script>");
                return "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any missing parameters in "reportParameterCollection" ? Have you tried to manually enter them by setting the ReportViewer ShowParameterPrompts="True"?

Comment: No, nothing is missing. I do not get any errors, it renders with no results. 

And it works perfectly using the parameter prompts.

Comment: This is an example of my URL:

http://myurl/reports/myapp.aspx?company=2&details=d&member=MemberName&acctmgr=false&act_status=&date_start=01%2f01%2f2012&date_end=03%2f14%2f2012

Comment: Can you try use only one parameter at a time to find the one that is giving you trouble?  So just specify AcctMgr and make sure that the SQL query should return some results.

Comment: I believe it is company. If the company id is not correct, 0 results are returned, which is what it is doing. However, 2 is a valid company id. I have tried explicitly typecasting company to an int, thinking it may be a type mismatch, but no luck.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  I don't remember now picky that report viewer is about variable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was act_status

According to reportviewer, apparently a url string with `&act_status=&...` Does not mean that `act_status = NULL`.

So I changed my SQL to reflect empty string as opposed to NULL.